# How to regroup an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of locations:

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Location 1",
    "city": {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Phoenix",
    }
 },
 {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Location 2",
    "city": {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Phoenix",
    }
 },
 {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Location 3",
    "city": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Los Angeles",
    }
 }
]
```

Out of that, I would like to create an array of cities, with each city having locations from that city.

Example result:

```
[
  {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Phoenix",
        "locations": [
               // location objects from Phoenix (Location 1 and Location 2)
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Location 1",
                "city": {
                  "id": 7,
                  "name": "Phoenix",
                 }
             },
             {
                 "id": 2,
                 "name": "Location 2",
                 "city": {
                    "id": 7,
                    "name": "Phoenix",
                  }
              }
        ]
  },
  {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Los Angeles",
        "locations": [
               // location objects from Los Angeles (Location 3)
            {
                 "id": 3,
                 "name": "Location 3",
                 "city": {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "Los Angeles",
                 }
             }
        ]
   }
]
```

I have tried using `.map()` and `.filter()` to get an array of unique values for cities. It didn't return unique, distinct values for the whole `city` (`return item.city`), so I used just the `name` property (`return item.city.name`) since I don't really care about city id. I got an array of unique city names:

```
var cities = data.map(function (item) {
    return item.city.name;
}).filter(function (value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
});
```

Now I'm stuck on constructing an array that would list locations as a property for each city. Thank you in advance...

Comment: Your expected result isn't valid javascript. Should `locations` be an object or an array?

Comment: @Mark_M `locations` should be an array of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first create an object with keys that are set to the city's id. Then if you need those objects in an array you just call map over the keys. For example create an object keyed to ID:

```js
var arr = [{"id": 1,"name": "Location 1","city": {"id": 7,"name": "Phoenix",}},{"id": 2,"name": "Location 2","city": {"id": 7,"name": "Phoenix",}},{"id": 3,"name": "Location 3","city": {"id": 11,"name": "Los Angeles",}}]

var obj = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (a[c.city.id]) a[c.city.id].push(c)
    else  a[c.city.id] = [c]
    return a
}, {})

console.log(obj)
```

Now you have a clean object, if you want an array just add a map over the keys:

```js
var arr = [{"id": 1,"name": "Location 1","city": {"id": 7,"name": "Phoenix",}},{"id": 2,"name": "Location 2","city": {"id": 7,"name": "Phoenix",}},{"id": 3,"name": "Location 3","city": {"id": 11,"name": "Los Angeles",}}]

var obj = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (a[c.city.id]) a[c.city.id].locations.push(c)
    else  a[c.city.id] = {name: c.city.name, locations:[c]}
    return a
}, {})

var arr_version = Object.keys(obj).map(k => Object.assign({id: k}, obj[k]))

console.log(arr_version)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I've been trying to do. I will try to decipher every step of this solution to understand it better.